# Grid View Edit/Update/Delete Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, aspxgridview

I am trying to add edit/update/delete hyperlink to each of the generated row so that if there is any error then the user can edit/update/delete it. I have looked for code that will make sense with the one i got but i was not able to. 
I am displaying data for the user so that multiple rows for the same ID can be submitted. This is not the actual code but similar in logic. I have several other fields that a user enters.

Thank you for your help in advance.

ASPX:

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="gridViewTest.WebForm2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div align="center" style="margin-top:50px;">
     <table align="center" style="border-collapse:collapse; width:500px;">
      <tr>
       <th align="left" colspan="4" style="color:#86ef12; border:1px solid #86ef12; padding:5px 10px;">Add Employees Details</th>        
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td style="border:1px solid #86ef12;padding:5px 10px;"> Employ ID :</td>
       <td style="border:1px solid #86ef12;"><asp:TextBox ID="txtempid" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
      </tr>      
      <tr>
       <td style="border:1px solid #86ef12;padding:5px 10px;"> Employ Name :</td>
       <td style="border:1px solid #86ef12;"><asp:TextBox ID="txtempname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
      </tr>      
      <tr>
       <td style="border:1px solid #86ef12;padding:5px 10px;"> Employ Salary :</td>
       <td style="border:1px solid #86ef12;"><asp:TextBox ID="txtempsalary" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td colspan="4" style="padding:5px 10px; text-align:center;border:1px solid #86ef12;">
        <asp:Button ID="btn_add" runat="server" Text=" ADD " onclick="btn_add_Click" />
       </td>
      </tr>
     </table>
     <br />
     <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" BackColor="White" 
            BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" 
            ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical">        
         <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
         <HeaderStyle BackColor="#006a4d" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
         <PagerStyle BackColor="#34b233" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
         <RowStyle BackColor="white" />
         <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
         <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FBFBF2" />
         <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#848384" />
         <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#EAEAD3" />
         <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#575357" />
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

CODE Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;


namespace gridViewTest
{
    public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect"].ConnectionString;


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("EmpID");
        dt.Columns.Add("EmpName");
        dt.Columns.Add("EmpSal");
        DataRow dr = null;
        if (ViewState["emp"] != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                dt = (DataTable)ViewState["emp"];
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    dr = dt.NewRow();
                    dr["EmpID"] = txtempid.Text;
                    dr["EmpName"] = txtempname.Text;
                    dr["EmpSal"] = txtempsalary.Text;
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["EmpID"] = txtempid.Text;
            dr["EmpName"] = txtempname.Text;
            dr["EmpSal"] = txtempsalary.Text;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        ViewState["emp"] = dt;

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Create a new DataTable.
        DataTable dtCustomers = new DataTable("Customers");

        //Add columns to DataTable.
        foreach (TableCell cell in GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells)
        {
            dtCustomers.Columns.Add(cell.Text);
        }

        //Loop through the GridView and copy rows.
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            dtCustomers.Rows.Add();
            for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                dtCustomers.Rows[row.RowIndex][i] = row.Cells[i].Text;
            }
        }

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand submitData = new SqlCommand("insertEmp", con);
            submitData.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            submitData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empInfo", dtCustomers);

            con.Open();

            try
            {
                submitData.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            con.Close();


        }


    }//end of button1_click



}
}
```

Comment: post your actual code.

Comment: sorry can't but this is exactly the same except for the column names

Comment: so its very hard to get answers as it seems too broad *edit/update/delete*.

Comment: once the user enters the information in the text fields and updates the grid view, i would like the user to have the ability to edit and update the row within grid view or if they have entered any row in error delete it before submission to the database

Comment: Did you try this? http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/9f0ae2/gridview-edit-delete-and-update-in-Asp-Net/ and https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Simple-Insert-Select-Edit-Update-and-Delete-in-ASPNet-GridView-control.aspx

Comment: @KhyatiDesai follow two links by Chetan. These can help you!